# Building perl 5.14.2 on windows - getting the error NMAKE : fatal error U1077: miniperl.exe' : return code '0x1'

Tags: windows, perl, nmake

Building perl 5.14.2 on windows - getting error NMAKE : fatal error U1077: miniperl.exe' : return code '0x1' while the following command is invoked after running "nmake -logo" from win32 folder under perl source.

../miniperl.exe -I../lib ../make_ext.pl "MAKE=nmake -nologo" --dir=../cpan --dir=../dist --dir=../ext --nonxs

Did anybody face this problem before? Please let me know

Comment: Why don't you try [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/beta/index.html) for Windows?

Comment: Are you sure that's the first error? It's simply saying that `make_ext.pl` returned an error, but I would expect `make_ext.pl` to announce any error it encountered.

Comment: @Alexandr Ciornii  - We are using Visual Studio 2005 compiler.

Comment: @mob - We are consuming the libperl.dll created from the perl source compilation to run perl scripts from C++ program? We are using the same perl source across UNIX and Windows platforms so i'm not sure if we can consume Strawberry Perl

Comment: If you followed all instructions in README.win32, report this error on p5p mailing list: http://lists.perl.org/list/perl5-porters.html . Mention all your changes to "win32/Makefile".

Comment: @yogiashaj - Maybe you can link against `%STRAWBERRY%/perl/lib/CORE/libperl514.a`?

Comment: @ikegami 
I'm getting the below error without much information
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '<folder>\miniperl.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
Unsuccessful make(cpan/Archive-Extract): code=512 at ..\make_ext.pl line 463.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '..\miniperl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Comment: @AlexandrCiornii We use a wrapper build over the perl build steps. I will go through the README and see i get any clue. If not, i will post into the DL you have mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Mac and Unix, Windows doesn't' come with a C compiler installed. Thus, it can be difficult to figure out exactly where things are going wrong without more information. For example, did you install the GCC compiler or another standard C compiler?

The easiest way to get the most recent and complete version of Perl on Windows is to use one of the two standard Windows distributions:

- [Straberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)
- [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads)

Many people like Strawberry Perl because it's a duplicate of what you find on Unix. The same modules, the same libraries. Others prefer ActivePerl because it includes by default all of the special Windows modules that you probably want to use on Windows to do things like update the registry, talk to the Windows domain to check credentials, etc.

The truth is that both of these versions are more or less the same. The two main complaints of why you should use one over the other:

- Strawberry Perl doesn't work with Win32
- Active Perl uses PPM and not CPAN.

Are both not correct. You can install and download the Win32 modules in Strawberry Perl and it'll run about every script that ActivePerl does.

And, Active Perl can now install the same C compiler Strawberry Perl uses if you want to install a module that requires compilation. The directions are [online](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl). It works with almost all the CPAN modules.

So, unless you have a special reason to build Perl from scratch, I recommend you just download ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl -- especially if you are not really familiar with C/C++ and Make.

Comment: We are consuming the libperl.dll created from the perl source compilation to run perl scripts from C++ program? We are using the same perl source across UNIX and Windows platforms so i'm not sure if we can consume Strawberry Perl. I will check.

Comment: Strawberry Perl is suppose to be the same source as Unix Perl. The Strawberry Perl people used the MINGW project to compile Perl. There is something called [App::perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/) that helps you build Perl on Windows. I never used it. However, you first need an installation of Perl (probably Strawberry Perl) to use it. The other thing you could do is contact the Strawberry Perl people for help on compiling Perl for Windows. After all, that's what they did.

Comment: The real reason NOT to use ActivePerl, is that its license agreement requires you to pay a commercial license ($1k/year) is it is installed on an Internet facing machine. It doesn't prevent you from installing it, but that's the license agreement and many people just ignore it. You can use CPAN on both, even on the old ActiveState built on MSVC. You just need the right dev env set.